# PDOException. Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an issue with my MySQL Query but I can't see anything wrong with what it's telling me. I'm developing on my local machine, and below is the database connection statement:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xsa_primary;charset=utf8', 'root', '',       array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Here is my actual query page (for a typeahead search function, typeahead.php):

```
$query = $_GET['query'].'%';

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT accountEmail FROM `xsa_accounts` WHERE accountEmail LIKE = :query");
$stmt->bindParam(':query', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$results = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

return json_encode($results);
```

I keep getting the following error on that page, I've tried many variations of my MySQL Query, including backticks (`) on everything and on specific things one at a time, etc.. still no luck.

The error is:

*Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ?' at line 1' in ..........\typeahead.php:8 Stack trace: #0 ..........\typeahead.php(8): PDO->prepare('SELECT accountE...') #1 {main} thrown in ..........\typeahead.php on line 8*

My MySQL table has the following columns (just for testing):

```
1   accountID PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
2   accountFirst
3   accountLast
4   accountEmail
5   accountPhone
```

What am I missing here? It's driving me insane. I've been staring at this for about 45 minutes now.

Comment: Remove `=` after `LIKE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT accountEmail FROM `xsa_accounts` WHERE accountEmail LIKE = :query");
```

with

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT accountEmail FROM `xsa_accounts` WHERE accountEmail LIKE :query");
```

You must remove `=` after `LIKE`

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not catching that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use and equal sign with `LIKE`

```
LIKE = :query  (bad)
LIKE :query (good)
```

Explicitly: change your SQL statement to this

```
 "SELECT accountEmail FROM `xsa_accounts` WHERE accountEmail LIKE :query"
```